# Python - Pandas combine two dataframes that provide different values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two diffent dataframes with two columns and i want to merge them + get them sum of column B. The problem is dataframe 1 have some data, that i want to keep. I'll write an example so it make sense

Dataframe 1

```
Columns A Column B
House     walls,doors,rooms
Animal    Legs,nose,eyes
car       tires,engine
```

Dataframe 2

```
Column A  Column B
House     windows,kitchen
Bike      wheels,bicycle chain
```

Desired result

```
Column A  Column B
House     walls,doors,rooms,windows,kitchen
Animal    Legs,nose,eyes
Car       tires,engine
Bike      wheels,bicycle chain
```

The merge function doesnt help and i tried to use pd.concat and then somehow aggregate data but didnt help either. Someone got an idea of how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby("Column A")["Column B"].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
```

After concating your dataframes, group your values by Column A, then use `apply` to concat the grouped strings in column B, and finally restore Column A with `reset_index()`.

**Edit: expansion on comments**

To remove duplicates, you can use the `set` data structure, which only keeps a single version of each element you put into it. For each row x, split the words, then convert the list of words into a set:

```
df4 = df3["Column B"].apply(lambda x: set(x.split(", "))).reset_index()
```

Note that after this, your column B will contain sets. I'll let you figure out how to reconvert from a set to a string using a similar pattern.

Comment: Awesome it work. Why is it you have to use reset_index when both dataframes got the same column names?

Comment: groupby() turns Column A into an index (try removing reset_index() and see what happens). With reset_index(), we tell the dataframe that we don't want that, we want to keep A as a normal column. You can play around with the different steps of the process (concat, groupby, etc...) and see how the dataframe looks at each step, it's a great way to understand how these functions work.

Comment: that is really helpful. Is it somehow possible to make it check for duplicate values when it uses groupby("Column A")["Column B"]? just so i make sure I wont get duplicate values in the column B? I think my problem is i do not understand in which way you can 'build' on your code without getting syntax errors. With your line of code there is both groupby, apply and reset_index in one line of code. Does it make sense?

Comment: Answer to part 1 in edited post. For the second part, you can break the line at each function and give it a name, which will allow you to see intermediary steps. Ex: df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]), df4 = df3.groupby("Column A"), etc...

Comment: Hmm It doesn't remove duplicate words, it only turns it into a set?

Comment: Sets by definition don't have duplicates. If you have "duplicates", you might have extra spaces at the start or end of your words that are making them different from each other.